# jsPDF-AutoTable: Showing multiple footers on page with more than one horizontal tables drawn side by side

Tags: jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I've created multiple tables with jsPDF-AutoTable, placed side by side. These table contents vary based on the data from my HTML page. So there may be more than one tables on the same page side by side. 
The problem am facing is that *the footer is get created for every pair of tables, so that the footer gets overlapped on each page.* 
This is the image of my PDF file.
[image]

```
 const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt',);
const totalPagesExp = '{total_pages_count_string}';
let first = null, last = null;

const footer = function (data) {
    var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,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'
    // HEADER
    pdf.setFontSize(20);
    pdf.setTextColor(40);
    pdf.setFontStyle('normal');

    if (imgData)
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 400, 30, 60, 60);

    let str = 'Page ' + pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    if (typeof pdf.putTotalPages === 'function')
        str = str + ' of ' + totalPagesExp;

    pdf.setFontSize(10);
    pdf.setFontStyle("normal");
    pdf.text(str, data.settings.margin.left + 470, pdf.internal.pageSize.height - 30);
    pdf.text('© 2019 mysite.com All Rights Reserved.', data.settings.margin.left, pdf.internal.pageSize.height - 30);
};

let y = 120;

$(".note").each(function () {
    const $frnt = $(this).find(".front");
    const $back = $(this).find(".back");
    y = pdf.autoTable.previous ? (first.finalY > last.finalY ? first.finalY + 25 : last.finalY + 25): y;

    pdf.autoTable({
        head: [[$frnt.find(".bk-title").text().trim().toString(), $frnt.find(".pgno").text().trim()]],
        body: [[{
            content: $back.find(".question").text().trim().toString(),
            colSpan: 2,
            styles: {halign: 'justify'}
        }]],
        startY: y,
        tableWidth: 200,
        styles: {
            cellWidth: 'wrap',
            valign: 'middle',
            font: 'times',
            fontSize: 12,
            overflow: 'linebreak'
        },
        headStyles: {
            fillColor: [247, 185, 7]
        },
        theme: 'striped',
        margin: {top: 150, right: 350},
        didDrawPage: footer
    });
    first = pdf.autoTable.previous;

    pdf.autoTable({
        head: [[$frnt.find(".bk-title").text().trim().toString(), $frnt.find(".pgno").text().trim()]],
        body: [[{content: $frnt.find(".title").text().trim().toString(), colSpan: 2, styles: {halign: 'justify'}}],
            [{content: $frnt.find(".desc").text().trim().toString(), colSpan: 2, styles: {halign: 'justify'}}]],
        startY: y,
        styles: {
            cellWidth: 'wrap',
            valign: 'middle',
            font: 'times',
            fontSize: 12,
            overflow: 'linebreak'
        },
        headStyles: {
            fillColor: [247, 185, 7]
        },
        theme: 'striped',
        margin: {top: 150, left: 340}
    });
    last = pdf.autoTable.previous;
    if (typeof pdf.putTotalPages === 'function')
        pdf.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);
});


pdf.save(`${username}'s Notes.pdf`);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution from [here](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/144#issuecomment-232106480). 
Here the tables are added dynamically. When there is more than one table at a page the footer get added corresponding to each table. That's why the footers get overlapped. Based on the above-mentioned solution I changed my code for `footer()` function as below:

```
let currentpage = 0;

const footer = function (data) {
    if (currentpage < pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages()) {
        var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,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'
        // HEADER
        pdf.setFontSize(20);
        pdf.setTextColor(40);
        pdf.setFontStyle('normal');

        if (imgData)
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 400, 30, 60, 60);

        let str = 'Page ' + pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
        if (typeof pdf.putTotalPages === 'function')
            str = str + ' of ' + totalPagesExp;

        pdf.setFontSize(10);
        pdf.setFontStyle("normal");
        pdf.text(str, data.settings.margin.left + 470, pdf.internal.pageSize.height - 30);
        pdf.text(`© ${new Date().getFullYear()} 3d-reader.com All Rights Reserved.`, data.settings.margin.left, pdf.internal.pageSize.height - 30);
        currentpage = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    }
};
```